# TaskbarItemInfo in Windows universal apps

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, taskbar

How can I define TaskbarItemInfo in my Windows universal app?

I want to add custom media playback button when the app thumbnail is displayed.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the same. I've declared in the app manifest that it is going to play background audio and somehow, the standard playback buttons are showing when I hover over the app in the taskbar, but they are always disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Nikolay, they are disabled by default. You have to explicitly turn them on/off by that statement:

```
SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView().ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;
SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView().IsPlayEnabled = true;
SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView().IsPauseEnabled = true;
```

See this for reference:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt228338.aspx